# Making sheet name variable in google-sheets as my new range reference in copyTo?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

This code works for me... when the sheet "Append" is given...

```
    function submit_me() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.getRange('Append!A30:CF30').activate();
 spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Responses').showSheet().activate();
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Responses'), true);
 spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
 spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
 spreadsheet.getRange('Append!A30:CF30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
 SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

};
```

Now I have successfully run a script that creates a new sheet names like "BAN3OY108646"...
And I am stuck not knowing how to convert my script from using given "Append" to using  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

Any help is truly appreciated. I feel I'm pretty close.
I have tried a multiple dozen times but I still can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
spreadsheet.getRange(sheetName + '!A30:CF30');
```